# Is is possible to create nested custom scopes for beans in spring?

Tags: spring

In my application, we have custom scope(scope=tenant) defined for beans which is set while the spring context is initialized but I need to further segregate beans based on scheme scope after logging in at run time. Is it possible to have nested scopes in spring?

Comment: Please provide a code example.